# laravelのpublicフォルダで静的HTMLファイルを配信するうえでの混在する文字コードの扱い方について

Tags: html, laravel, 文字コード, shift-jis

laravel6.x系で静的なHTMLファイルを配信したいと考えています。
その際にpublicフォルダを利用しようとしていますが、問題があります。

例）

```
public/hogeA/index.html　←Shift_JIS
public/hogeB/index.html　←UTF-8
public/hogeC/index.html　←Shift_JIS
```

上記のようにフォルダごとのindex.htmlで、Shift_JISとUTF-8のファイルが混在している場合、
今回の例で言うと、hogeAとhogeCのindex.htmlがブラウザで見たときに文字化けしてしまいます。

hogeAのResponse HeaderのContent-Typeをみると、text/html; charset=UTF-8にっているのが原因なのはわかっています。

publicフォルダの特定フォルダ以下のhtmlのResponse HeaderのContent-Typeを強制的にcharset=Shift_JISにする方法はあるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

該当の HTML ファイル中で適切なエンコーディングを返すよう META タグで指定することができます。

以下は UTF-8 を指定する例ですが、Shift_JIS の場合は "Shift_JIS" となるようです。

**参考:**
[HTMLで文字エンコーディングを指定する](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations.ja)

> ```html
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html lang="en">
> <head>
> <meta charset="utf-8"/>
> ```

> ```html
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html lang="en">
> <head>
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
> ```